# How to call data from SQLite database with two conditions dynamically?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database of stocks from all countries. I want to call data on ticker basis from a
specific stock exchange or country because some tickers are same from different countries like
AMZN from NASDAQ or BMV or WBAG exchanges, the data is not showing properly. What should I do
in order the data is properly displayed against a specific country dynamically?

```
SELECT security.id, security.country, ticker, full_name, exchange_code FROM 
 security LEFT JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = exchange_id WHERE ticker = 'AMZN'
```

with this query I got these dataset with the ticker name which is not what I want?

```
99  ARGENTINA   AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  BCBA
1504    AUSTRIA AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  WBAG
15301   ITALY   AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  MIB
21455   MEXICO  AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  BMV
22551   PAKISTAN    AMZN    MEEZAN BANK LTD PSX
37100   UNITED STATES   AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  NASDAQ

SELECT security.id, security.country, ticker, full_name, exchange_code FROM security
LEFT JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = exchange_id WHERE ticker = 'AMZN' AND exchange_code = 
'NASDAQ'
```

I want something  like this dynamically

```
37100   UNITED STATES   AMZN    AMAZON.COM INC  NASDAQ
```

Code:

```
#Import libraries 
import sqlite3, config
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import Cursor
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

#Fast API web framework 

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request):
connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = connection.cursor()

#SQLiTE query to call data from database from security table

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT id, country, ticker, full_name FROM security ORDER BY country
""")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "id": id, "stocks" : 
rows})

@app.get("/stock/{ticker}")
def stock_detail(request: Request, ticker):
connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = connection.cursor()
 
#SQLITE query to call data against a specific ticker

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT security.id, ticker, full_name, exchange_code FROM security
    LEFT JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = exchange_id WHERE ticker = ?
""", (ticker,))

row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM security_price WHERE security_id = ? ORDER BY date DESC
""", (row['id'],))

prices = cursor.fetchall()

return templates.TemplateResponse("stock_detail.html", {"request": request, "id": id, "stock" 
: row, "bars" : prices})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. The body of a function has to be indented more than the `def` line.

Comment: If you want to get it from a specific country, you need to make that another parameter to the controller function.

Comment: Then just add `AND country = ?` to the SQL.

Comment: Thanks but it says...sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: Of course you need to add the variable with the country to the parameter tuple.

Comment: So `(ticker,)` becomes `(ticker, country)`

Comment: I am finance guy ... would you please guide me what should be proper code there because now it says ..NameError: name 'country' is not defined

Comment: How did you know how to write all that original code if you don't understand how to add this one little change?

Comment: hahaha...actually I am watching a tutorial and following that guy but his code is different from mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another route with the country and add that to the query.

```
@app.get("/stock/{ticker}/{country}")
def stock_detail_country(request: Request, ticker, country):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    #SQLITE query to call data against a specific ticker

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT security.id, ticker, full_name, exchange_code FROM security
        LEFT JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = exchange_id WHERE ticker = ? AND country = ?
    """, (ticker, country))

    row = cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM security_price WHERE security_id = ? ORDER BY date DESC
    """, (row['id'],))

    prices = cursor.fetchall()

    return templates.TemplateResponse("stock_detail.html", {"request": request, "id": id, "stock" 
    : row, "bars" : prices})
```

Comment: now it says ....{"detail":"Not Found"} when I click on ticker